# Word for when someone is freed of all charges or all charges dropped against them

Tags: word-request, legalese

What is one word for someone against whom initially there were some charges of wrongdoing but later is freed of all such charges or charges dropped against them formally or by a court? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: I think I'm looking for opposite/antonym of **indict**, if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any of these words: **acquit**, **absolve**, **exonerate**, **exculpate** and **vindicate**.

While it's alright to ask these questions in a question-answer forum, you would have your answers much faster if you just search the internet for antonym/synonym of the word. There are many websites that already have a list of synonyms and antonyms.

Cheers!

Comment: In the United States, an acquittal is a decision by a "trier of fact" (such as a jury, or (by mutual agreement of the prosecutor and the defendant) a judge).  Having "all charges dropped", or having all charges dismissed before "the case goes to the jury", or winning an appeal, is not the same as an acquittal.  A lawyer could tell you how this distinction is related to the American Constitution's prohibition of "double jeopardy".

Comment: @Jasper thanks for pointing that out. I would really appreciate if you could link a more detailed explanation of the same for the benefit of all.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is

> cleared
>
> He has been *cleared* of all charges,